# Accessing service layer from different goroutines for concurrent execution

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have different Clients, each has its own goroutines which reads messages from a websocket.

Those clients have in their a struct a Service struct that processes messages and updates the DB (postgres) accordingly.
Once the processing is finished, it send the output to a central Hub struct via a channel.

**My question is** - is the ProcessMessage func of Service done concurrently?
Meaning, are the message processing, DB interactions, etc. done concurrently in the example posted here? or is each processing **blocking** all the rest ?

Main :

```
func main() {

    ...

    // delivery channel (service --> hub)
    delivery := make(chan []byte)

    // hub
    hub := connection.NewHub(delivery)
    go hub.Run()

    // service
    service := chat.NewService(delivery, storage, cache)
}
```

Then for each connecting client, I create a Client struct, passing the Service and the Hub to it.

Also, each Client's reading from a websocket is done in a goroutine :

```
func ServeWs(hub *Hub, service chat.Service, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    client := &Client{hub: hub, conn: conn, service: service, send: make(chan []byte, 256)}
    client.hub.register <- client

    go client.writePump()
    go client.readPump()
}
```

Client :

```
func (c *Client) readPump() {
    for {
        _, message, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
        ...
        ...
        message = bytes.TrimSpace(bytes.Replace(message, newline, space, -1))
        ...
        c.service.ProcessMessage(message)
    }
 }
```

Service :

```
func (s *service) ProcessMessage(incoming protocol.Incoming) {

    is this blocking other clients? or is is executed concurrently for each Client ?

    // all the logic with postgres, redis, etc...
    result, ok := s.storage.InsertMessage(...)
    ...
    ...
    s.delivery <- result // sends the output to Hub via the delivery channel
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking - each goroutine runs concurrently, that's the purpose of a goroutine.

Comment: The Client goroutine - yes. But, the service's ProcessMessage is not run as a goroutine, which means all client goroutines access the same Service struct and func. Since I'm new to Go, I wasn't sure whether the Service's ProcessMessage func is executed for each client concurrently, or are they blocking each other. I thought maybe I have to explicitly call `go c.service.ProcessMessage(message)` to have it run concurrently.

Comment: You're calling `ProcessMessage` from inside `readPump`, and you appear to be running `readPump` in a goroutine per client, so you can have multiple concurrent `ProcessMessage` calls as shown. `s.delivery <- result` could potentially be blocking, and obviously I can't speak to any of the code that's been elided.

Comment: yes the delivery channel is deliberately blocking, the Hub receives the outgoing messages through it, and acts as a "controller" to send those to appropriate client.
But the main thing I wanted to make sure in go, is that all the logic and db transactions in the case of ProcessMessage are done concurrently by the multiple clients, which now I understand is in fact the case.
Thank you very much!